# Slow DNS resolution inside docker container

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

I've stuck with a problem of a very slow DNS resolution inside docker container. Simple GET to a 'google.com' takes about 4s to finish while the same request on host takes 0.052 ms. Also request works perfectly if I send it to an IP address that's why I suggested DNS problem. I've searched for an answer most of them were about setting dns servers in a `/etc/docker/daemon.json`  which I did but that didn't help my problem. Server runs on Ubuntu 16.04. I also have a dev server which runs same configurations but it works fine.

**Host:**

```
time curl -g 'google.com'

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s

time nslookup google.com

Server:     188.93.16.19
Address:    188.93.16.19#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.102
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.138
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.73.101


real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s
```

**Container:**

```
time curl -g https://google.com

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

real    0m4.592s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.012s

time nslookup google.com

Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.101
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.102
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.165.138


real    0m4.029s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.004s
```

**daemon.json**:

```
{
    "dns": ["188.93.16.19", "188.93.17.19", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.8.4"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by removing every DNS server except 8.8.8.8 from daemon.json. This is the only one server that resolves domain fast in my case. Tested differrent servers via `docker run --dns=<dns server> <image name> curl -g 'google.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue while using docker-compose.  It was a dns issue as well.
I added:

```
services: 
  my_app:
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.4.4.4
```

To my docker-compose.yml and it fixed the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to the bridge MAC address issue as outlined [here](https://backreference.org/2010/07/28/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports/).
You have to add a dummy interface with low MAC address as a slave to the bridge